# Access HTML elements from embedded object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage as an embedded object on another webpage. I am trying to access a class selector within the embedded object from the parent page. The class is not being found.

JS:

```
$myObj = $('.embeddedObject').contents().find('.findDiv');
if($myObj.length) {
    console.log("object found");
}
```

HTML on parent:

```
<div class="embeddedObject">
    <object data="testing.html"></object>
</div>
```

HTML on testing.html

```
<div class="findDiv">testing test</div>
```

The div is not being found despite that fact that I know it exists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is ```embeddedObject``` an iframe? Might be cross-origin policy issue...

Comment: You can't access stuff that is cross domain, it is a violation/security issue.

Comment: It's not a cross domain issue. They're both on the same domain. (e.g. xyz.com/parent.html, xyz.com/testing.html)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery context is not pointed to the correct element.  If you take a look at the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/), you can see that jQuery selectors can take in a second argument (context).

After the selector, you can specify a DOM Element, Document, or jQuery that it will use to look for your selector.